# Creating a list from the values that were copied in excel

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a list from the values that I copied from MS excel cells. For example; I copied first 5 row in the first column and want to make a list like this:

```
a_list=[2503531709, 4789009637, 8171670652, 8434851938, 9629960060]
```

I see that the pyperclip takes the values like this

```
'2503531709\r\n4789009637\r\n8171670652\r\n8434851938\r\n9629960060\r\n'
```

I wrote the following one. I did [i:i+9] just for this case. The length of values may be more than 10.

```
import pyperclip
isbn=pyperclip.paste()
a_list=[]

for i in range(len(isbn)):
    if ('\r') or ('\n') not in isbn[i:i+9]:
        a_list.append(isbn[i:i+9])

print(a_list)
```

The code did not work as I expected. How can I differentiate the values and add to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `str.split`:

`a_list = isbn.split('\r\n')`

If you want the values to be integers:

`a_list = [int(val) for val in isbn.split('\r\n') if val]`

Comment: I saw you removed the `map` solution. `map` can also be used, just make sure that it discards the last empty element. For example by using: `a_list = list(map(int, isbn.split('\r\n')[:-1]))`. Last element is empty because isbn string ends with the delimiter used by the split method call.